# Python: Find String in Tupler

Tags: python, string, variables

I have tried to change my 2 lists(old code) into one tupler and I'm having some problems (I have commented on the lines where it doesn't work). How do i find a string in tupler using a variable?

```
def main_tup():
    tup = tuple()

    while True:
        print "\nMenu for list"
        print "  1: Insert"
        print "  2: Lookup"
        print "  3: Exit program"

        choice = raw_input()
        print "Alternative chosen: ", choice

        if choice == "1":
            insert(tup)
        elif choice == "2":
            look(tup)
        elif choice == "3":
            break
        else:
            print "Error: Not a valid choice"

def insert(tup):
    ins = raw_input("Word to insert: ")
    if ins not in tup:                     #doesn't work
        pass
    else:
        print "Error: Word already exist"
        return
    desc = (raw_input("Description of word: "))
    tup = tup + (ins,desc)

def look(tup):
    up = raw_input("Word to lookup: ")
    if up not in tup:                            #doesn't work
        print "Error: Word not found"
        return
    i = 0
    while up != tup[i]:
        i += 2
    if up == tup[i]:
        print "Description of word: ", tup[i+1]
```

Comment: Thank you both for the useful answers! Helped me a ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tuple`s are immutable; when you do something like `tup = tup + (ins, desc)`, it's changing the **local** name `tup` to refer to a whole new `tuple` with the additional contents, but the `tuple` passed as an argument by the caller is unchanged (`insert` just drops its reference to it). Since `insert` just changes its local version of `tup` without returning it, the caller's (`main_tup`'s) `tup` never changes; it's always the empty `tuple` (`()`).

The easiest solution is to have `insert` end with `return tup` and have the call to `insert` change to `tup = insert(tup)`. You could also use a `list` instead of a `tuple` and `append`/`extend` the `list` (`list`s are mutable, so if you don't actually reassign them, modification to a `list` argument affects the caller's `list` too).

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the following code, `not in` *does* work for tuples:

```
>>> t = ('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> 'a' in t
True
>>> 'x' in t
False
>>> 'x' not in t
True
```

I think your problem is a different one: Tuples are *immutable*, therefore when they are manipulated in your `insert()` method, the `tup` in `main()` doesn't change and will always be empty.

This is one of the main differences between tuples and lists.

For your code to work, you'd need to `return` the new tuple from `insert()` back to your `main()` method.